# Storing values to a variable php

Tags: php

I have this php code in which i attempted to store a value from three select input into a one variable. it is not working. what is the right way? or is that possible?

```
$REGDATE = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST["month"]) "/" ($_POST["day"]) "/" ($_POST["year"]);
```

Comment: And the question is?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is to concatenate the strings

```
mysql_real_escape_string( 
  $_POST["month"] . "/" . 
  $_POST["day"] .  "/" . 
  $_POST["year"] )
```

As mentioned there are better ways of doing this, but for what you're doing you need to join the strings together.